# Getting error that the database is locked when refreshing the page

Tags: linux, apache, sqlite, permissions, mod-mono

I am running apache with mod mono and my asp.net app is using mono sqlite as its db. When i refresh the page twice i get the DB is locked error. The folder it is in is chmod 777. The webapp is creating sqlite.db and sqlite.db-journal but it doesnt seem to be able to delete the journal. Also it has problems when i load the page once. It definitely seems to be a permission problem.

i'm confused. What permissions do i need to set these? i tried precreating the files using 777 and had no luck.

-edit- I didnt find a solution however i thought how silly i was being since i was planning to use mysql for my webapp. So i just ported the code and i no longer had issues.

Comment: Joke titles help neither you nor future searches via google.

Comment: You should've also added in the tags that you use mod_mono. For php for example you can use suPHP to "solve" permission problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating/deleting a file the directory permission matter.

So, if you really want that, you have to set the containing directory's permissions to 777.

Sample:

```
$ ls -la
total 21
dr-xr-xr-x  2 me me  1024 May 22 19:19 .          #no write permissions to directory
drwxrwxrwt 21 root   root   19456 May 22 19:19 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 me me     0 May 22 19:19 abc        #all permissions to file abc
$ rm abc
rm: cannot remove `abc': Permission denied        #abc has 777, but deleting doesn't work
$ chmod 777 .                                     #change directoy's permissions
$ rm abc                                          #now removing works
$ ls                                              #file abc is gone
```

The reason is that when you delete a file, you actually modify **the directory** and not **the file** itself.

Think of a hard link: The file itself will not change when you delete one hardlink to it, but the directory changes.

Comment: ok that is fine but as i said the folder it is in is also 777. So i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like one instance of the session in apache is blocking the other session, i.e. has the db file open exclusively. Try to let the database(model) run as a singleton (or similar) which all sessions access.

Comment: This problem doesnt occur on windows. Also it looks like the main db (not the journal) is not being written to at all (when i precreated the file and chmod 777 the file was 0 bytes after refreshing the page and nothing had a lock since i just made it)